# Npm install&&npm run dev why isn't it working?

Tags: php, laravel

I did npm install&&npm run dev and this is what happend do you know a fix for this. I don't know were to type in use stats.childre: true so can you figer it out for me.

```
egg@macbook-air-von-egg Ecommerce % npm install&&npm run dev
1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors and 3 warnings
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/egg/.npm/_logs/2021-06-26T16_54_50_520Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/egg/.npm/_logs/2021-06-26T16_54_50_638Z-debug.log
egg@macbook-air-von-egg Ecommerce %
```

Comment: Probably you must delete `node_modules` folder and execute `npm install`. After that you can try again to run `npm run dev`, or maybe `npm update` will be good

Comment: Both did not work.

Comment: Maybe your version of nodejs not relevant for your project. If project was wrote for one version, and you try running it with another same situation can be